# trying to replace an array of strings with a new array

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want to repalce an array with a new one but only the first string is replaced.
The new array is from a mysql table so I cant specify the exact strings.

```
$str = "##Random Stirng## ..... ##Random Stirng##";
$pattern = array ("str1" => "first replacement", "str2" => "second replacement");
$replacement = array('/##[^#]+##/','/##[^#]+##/');
echo preg_replace($replacement, $pattern, $str);
```

I want to replace the first IP-Address with the first replacement and the secon IP-address with the second replacement but instead both IP-Addresses are replaced with the first replacement.

Comment: 1) You've exchanged pattern & replacement in the preg_replace call. 2) Please, give some example strings and expected result.

Comment: seems like, first replacement become input for second replacement. works based upon reference itself.

Comment: `"str2" => "second replacement` missing `double quotes` at the end

Comment: @RakeshJakhar seems like that is typo while raising this question itself.

Comment: should array keys be the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php) is your friend:

```
$str = "##Random String## ..... ##Random String##";
$replacement = array ("first replacement", "second replacement");
$i = 0;
$res = preg_replace_callback(
            '/##[^#]+##/', 
            function($m) use(&$i, $replacement) {
                return $replacement[$i++];
            },
            $str);
echo $res;
```

**Output:**

```
first replacement ..... second replacement
```

Comment: thank you very much. I didnt understand how preg replace callback worked so I had to read about it first. but it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `str_replace`

```
$str = "##Random Stirng## ..... ##Random Stirng##";
$pattern = array("Random Stirng", "Random Stirng");
$replacement = array('1','2');
echo str_replace($pattern, $replacement, $str);
```

Comment: this is only an example. I have a big mysql table with many IP-adresses that need to be replaced.
That's why I put them between the "##".